# Why the blob value is not stored in the sqlite database in android

Tags: android, sqlite

I have written the following code for inserting video bytes into the database
**DBAdapter.java**

```
public void insertVideoBytesInVideoDownloadsTable(int id, byte[] videoBytes){
    ContentDBHelper dbHelper = new ContentDBHelper(context);
    sqliteDB = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    String sqlInsertVideoBytes = "Insert into " + tbl_video_downloads + " values (?, ?)";
    Log.i(TAG, sqlInsertVideoBytes);
    SQLiteStatement insertStatement = sqliteDB.compileStatement(sqlInsertVideoBytes);
    insertStatement.clearBindings();
    insertStatement.bindLong(1, id);
    Log.i(TAG, "Inserted: "+id);
    insertStatement.bindBlob(2, videoBytes);
    Log.i(TAG, "Inserted: "+videoBytes);
    insertStatement.executeInsert();
    Log.i(TAG, "Execute inserted");
   }
```

**StoreVideoInDB.java**

```
   public String downloadAndStoreVideoInDB(String urlPath){
        try {
            Log.i(TAG , "URL " +urlPath);
            URL url = new URL(urlPath);
            URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();
            InputStream videoStream = connection.getInputStream();
            BufferedInputStream videoBufferedStream = new BufferedInputStream(videoStream,128);
            ByteArrayBuffer videoByteArray = new ByteArrayBuffer(500);

            //Get the bytes one by one
            int current = 0;
            while((current = videoBufferedStream.read())!= -1){
                videoByteArray.append((byte)current);
                //Log.i(TAG, String.valueOf(current));
            }
            dbAdapter.insertVideoBytesInVideoDownloadsTable(id, videoByteArray.toByteArray());
        }catch (IOException ex) {
            Log.e(TAG, "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return path;
 }
```

**DDMS Log:**

```
01-16 16:03:13.563: INFO/DronaDBAdapter(18235): Insert into video_downloads values (?, ?)
01-16 16:03:13.563: INFO/DBAdapter(18235): Inserted: 1
01-16 16:03:13.573: INFO/DBAdapter(18235): Inserted: [B@44f35120
01-16 16:03:13.653: INFO/DBAdapter(18235): Execute inserted
```

As per the DDMS, the values 1(ID) and [B@44f35120 (Video Blob) values are showing successfully. But they are not inserted in DB.

When I check the DB and query as follows:

```
select * from video_downloads;
```

Result:

```
 1 |
```

The second field is blank! No blob value is inserted! Why? Is there any thing wrong in my code

Comment: perhaps, convert your videoBytes into base64 and then save in database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are misreading the output of the select. Your data is there, but the "select" does not show it, as it does not know what to do with the blob. Output its bytes literally makes no sense for most kinds of blobs.

Try reading the data back from your code and it will be there.

Comment: but whenever i checked in my prev projects on querying it showed blob data. This time it is not showing.

Comment: thanks. i got to see the data. i opened the database in Sqlite browser